# What is this aircraft, when was it produced and used and what was its role?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What aircraft is this, when was it produced, used operationally, and what was its role?

[image]

Comment: If you just look at the main landing gear arrangement, you may start suspecting it's a Tupolev :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is [a Tu-128](http://englishrussia.com/2014/12/30/some-abandoned-tu-128-planes-of-rzhevsk/).

In particular it seems to be the "UT" (training) variant:

[image]

Image [source](http://www.airvectors.net/avtu128.html)

> Full-scale production of the aircraft began in 1966, with 188 Tu-128s built to 1970, that total apparently including the prototype. Ten "Tu-128UT" trainers were built as well, with a new cockpit for a flight instructor fitted into a swollen nose.

Other info on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-28)

> The Tupolev Tu-28 (NATO reporting name Fiddler) was a long-range interceptor aircraft introduced by the Soviet Union in the 1960s. The official designation was Tu-128, but this designation was less commonly used in the West.

[...]

> The Tu-128's only publicly reported combat operation was the destruction of NATO reconnaissance balloons. The aircraft remained in service until 1990.